# Error when using AWK Command for Filtering and Matching Data from Two Files

Tags: awk

I have two files one which includes 3 columns, called Chromosome and Gene_start Gene_end. The first column contains a number and Gene_start Gene_end contains a numeric value.

```
>> cat gene_positions.txt
Chromosome Gene_start Gene_end 
15 26788693 27189686
1 22004791 22115099
20 44689624 44723591
20 61872136 61909046
```

I have another file with 14 columns, I am only intrested in the first two columns of this file. CHROM and POS:

```
>> cat gwas_results.txt
CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  L95 U95 T_STAT  P
1   22004791    1:54712:T:TTTTC T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00256645 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818212  0.934799
1   22105000    1:54712:T:TC    T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00259875 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818216  0.94799
1   825410  rs13303179:825410:G:A   G   A   G   ADD 1597    -0.017462   0.0235123   -0.0635454  0.0286213   -0.742676   0.457788
```

If the first column from file 1 matches exactly to the first column of the second file as well as the second column of gwas_results.txt called POS falls within the range of the second and third column of file 1 (Gene_start Gene_end) for the line to printed in the output_test.txt. Essentially, the gene_positions is a lookup file, with three columns and the first is a number that should match the first column of the gwas_results.txt, next if the POS in gwas_results.txt falls within the range of the Gene_start Gene_end from the first file, I want the line from gwas_results.txt to be printed.

I am using the following awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {chromosome[$1]; start[$1]; end[$1]; next} 
   ($1 in chromosome) && ($2 >= start[$1]) && ($2 <= end[$1]) {print}'\
 gene_positions.txt gwas_results.txt > test_output_results.txt
```

I get 0 output and 0 in the error file. What am I doing wrong.

Expected output:

```
1   22004791    1:54712:T:TTTTC T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00256645 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818212  0.934799
1   22105000    1:54712:T:TC    T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00259875 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818216  0.94799
```

BECAUSE... The first column of 'gwas_results.txt' ($1) matches a value in the first column of 'gene_positions.txt'.
The second column of 'gwas_results.txt' ($2) falls within the range defined by the second and third columns of 'gene_positions.txt' (Gene_start and Gene_end) for chromosome 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```bash
awk '
NR == FNR {
   beg[$1] = $2
   end[$1] = $3
   next
}
$1 in beg && beg[$1] <= $2 && $2 <= end[$1]
' gene_positions.txt gwas_results.txt

1   22004791    1:54712:T:TTTTC T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00256645 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818212  0.934799
1   22105000    1:54712:T:TC    T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00259875 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818216  0.94799
```

If you want header as well then use:

```bash
awk '
NR == FNR {
   beg[$1] = $2
   end[$1] = $3
   next
}
FNR == 1 || ($1 in beg && beg[$1] <= $2 && $2 <= end[$1])
' gene_positions.txt gwas_results.txt

CHROM   POS ID  REF ALT A1  TEST    OBS_CT  BETA    SE  L95 U95 T_STAT  P
1   22004791    1:54712:T:TTTTC T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00256645 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818212  0.934799
1   22105000    1:54712:T:TC    T   TTTTC   T   ADD 1597    -0.00259875 0.0313666   -0.0640439  0.058911    -0.0818216  0.94799
```

---

In your code you are using this: `start[$1]; end[$1];`

which makes `start` and `end` associative array with keys as `$1` and value as null. You are not storing desired values `$2` and `$3` in these 2 arrays.

Moreover you don't even need `chromosome` array just to check for presence of `$1` in that array since both `start` and `end` arrays will have keys as `$1` only so you can either use `$1 in start` or `$1 in end` (or just omit this condition altogether like this:

```
beg[$1] <= $2 && $2 <= end[$1]
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works.

Comment: @HKJ3: I have added it in my answer.

Comment: I have a question following this. The code didn't work as planned because my gene_positions is quite a long list (100 lines). However, when I look at my output I get some positions outside the range specified, line by line, for each CHROM and POS.

Comment: 100 lines is not a big deal for awk to process. If you want you can provide a fresh set of sample data by editing your question that can reproduce the problem. Do add your expected output as well so that I can investigate from my end.

Comment: Hello, I have just posted another question! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Addressing why OP's current code does not work ...

OP mentions in the description:

> The second column of 'gwas_results.txt' ($2) falls within the range
> defined by the **second and third columns** of 'gene_positions.txt'
> (Gene_start and Gene_end) for chromosome 1.

While in their code we see:

```
NR==FNR {chromosome[$1]; start[$1]; end[$1]; next} 
                         ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^
```

Where `start[$1]` and `end[$1]` create array entries with `$1` as the index and `<nothing>` as the value stored in the array entries, ie, the array entries are empty/blank so when we get to the test we're actually testing against empty/blank values:

```
($2 >= start[$1]) && ($2 <= end[$1])
       ^^^^^^^^^==empty     ^^^^^^^==empty
```

The solution is to assign values to the array entries, eg:

```
'NR==FNR {chromosome[$1]; start[$1]=$2; end[$1]=$3; next}
                                   ^^^         ^^^
```